# NVIDIA Nsight Systems CLI not getting memory statistics

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight

I'm using NVIDIA Nsight Systems cli (`nsys`) to profile a simple cuda program (vectors adding). I've already checked the documentation but I think I'm missing something.

I'm running the `nsys profile` command with  `--stats=true` flag.

```
CUDA API Statistics:

 Time(%)  Total Time (ns)  Num Calls    Average      Minimum     Maximum            Name
 -------  ---------------  ---------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------

CUDA Kernel Statistics:

 Time(%)  Total Time (ns)  Instances    Average      Minimum     Maximum                       Name
```

And this is what I'm getting back (values omitted). Should I enable a certain flag to show memory statistics?

*tested with the `--trace=cuda` flag but again no memory statistics*

- Host: Windows 10
- Cuda Toolkit version: 11.0
- Nvidia Nsight version: 2021.1.1

Is this a compatibility problem between Windows and Cuda should I downgrade? I really don't know.
When I run the same command in Ubuntu is working properly.  It's really driving me crazy.

Any help is welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [memory operation statistics](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#example-output-stats-option) you are referring to track unified memory (UM) **demand-paged** transfer activity.

The UM model on windows [does not used demand-paged transfer of data](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements), so you won't see these sections on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way I can track this transfer activity on windows ?